# How to change default value with click function?

Tags: javascript

```
function navigation() {
    var navigation = {
        value:1
    };              
    return navigation.value;        
    $( '#cookie_outside').click( function() {
        var navigation = {
            value:0
        };
        return navigation.value;                                
    });

    $( '#cookie_inside' ).click( function() {
        var navigation = {
            value:1
        };
        return navigation.value;
    });             
}

swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    slidesPerView: 'auto', 
    parallax: false,
    initialSlide: navigation(),
    grabCursor: true, 
    resistanceRatio: .00000000000001
});
```

How can i change default value with click function. "initialSlide: navigation()".

My default value is 1, i want it change when i clicked #cookie_inside or #cookie_outside.

It can be possible instant change?

Comment: You know there is something seriously wrong with your `navigation` function. (a) You have a return statement fairly early, which means the rest of the function won’t run. (b) did you mean to use a variable with the _same_ name of the function? That will replace the function with the new data — that’s OK if you are replacing it with another function, but here you are replacing it with an object.

Answer (score 0):

Your `event` binding is never triggered due to `return` statement and another reason is the binding of `event` must be done outside your function. On your `ready` function do call `setup`

```
function navigation() {
    var navigation = {
        value:1
    };              
    return navigation.value;                
}

function setup()
{
    $( '#cookie_outside').click( function() {
        var navigation = {
            value:0
        };
        return navigation.value;                                
    });

    $( '#cookie_inside' ).click( function() {
        var navigation = {
            value:1
        };
        return navigation.value;
    }); 
}

$(document).ready(function(){

    //set it up
    setup();
});
```

Comment: swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
 slidesPerView: 'auto', 
 parallax: false,
 initialSlide: navigation.value,
 grabCursor: true, 
 resistanceRatio: .00000000000001
});

What can i write here?

Comment: you need to recreate Swiper object on click

Comment: how can i do this?

Comment: ScanQR is right, but his function returns new value every time. Play and try to understand this: https://jsbin.com/qusaxebofi/edit?html,js,output. Also, read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions